# Google Mobile Playbook Drag Navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile, navigation, slider, drag

I've been scratching my head on how to replicate the draggable navigation on Google's Mobile Playbook seen here http://www.themobileplaybook.com/

I am creating a website using jQuery Mobile and am having no luck with this. Has anyone done something like this with jQuery?

-Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day or two I figured out how to do this using jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable!

This got me started in the right direction http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/wWbUF/1/